# Set StyleSheetTheme in @Page directive in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, themes, stylesheet, page-directives

I have a property in asp.net application

```
ABPS.PRR.WEB.CurrentSession.Theme
```

and I'm setting it in @Page directive in aspx pages like:

```
<%@ Page StylesheetTheme="ABPS.PRR.WEB.CurrentSession.Theme"  Title="Default" ... %>
```

but I'm getting runtime error

```
Parser Error Message: Theme 'ABPS.PRR.WEB.CurrentSession.Theme' cannot be found in the application or global theme directories.
```

How can I implement this in page directive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`StylesheetTheme` requires a theme name and you are supplying this in the wrong way.

If you want to set the theme at runtime then you need to store it in a session variable, you can do it like...

```
protected void Page_PreInit(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Page.StylesheetTheme = ABPS.PRR.WEB.CurrentSession.Theme;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to set other value to the StyleSheetTheme property of a page, you'll need to override it:

```
public override string StyleSheetTheme
{
    get
    {
        return ABPS.PRR.WEB.CurrentSession.Theme;
    }
    set
    {
    }
}
```

But if you want to change the Theme property, just set its value in the Page_PreInit event:

```
protected void Page_PreInit(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Theme = ABPS.PRR.WEB.CurrentSession.Theme;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could set it in the code.

Put this in the Page_PreInit method.

```
Page.Theme = ABPS.PRR.WEB.CurrentSession.Theme
```

or

```
Page.StyleSheetTheme = ABPS.PRR.WEB.CurrentSession.Theme
```